# Abstracting Intranet and Internet router with third router

Tags: networking, internet, intranet, mikrotik

**Intranet network:**

- Default gateway: 10.10.10.1
- Mask: 255.255.255.128
- DNS:  155.18.71.103
- addresses are assigned statically. Range from 10.10.10.5 - 10.10.10.50

**Internet network:**

- Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
- mask: 255.255.255.0
- DNS:  8.8.8.8
- this router leases addresses with DHCP.

Intranet is used to access only one webapp on intranet (webapp.com).
In current setup I have one computer for  intranet and second for internet.

I want add new router, hEX lite RB750R2 from mikrotik and connect one interface to Intranet router, second interface on Internet router and the third interface would be local LAN with DHCP that connects to switch.

How to configure HEX router so that I can use only one  computer with one wired NIC to access both services, Intranet and Internet?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is mostly just regular routing.

1. Choose two interfaces (e.g. ether1/2) for the upstream connections.
2. Remove both interfaces from any bridges.
   `/interface/bridge/port`
3. Configure suitable IP addresses on the interfaces.
   `/ip/address`, `/ip/dhcp-client`
4. If using the default "defconf" configuration, add both interfaces to the "WAN" interface list, so that the defconf NAT rule will match them.
   `/interface/list/member`
5. If *not* using defconf, add firewall NAT rules (in the "prerouting" chain) with "out-interface" that matches both interfaces, with action "masquerade".
   `/ip/firewall/nat`
6. If your intranet webapp is not within your subnet, add appropriate routes towards the webapp's IP address through the intranet gateway.
   `/ip/route`
7. If you need to use the intranet DNS server to look up the webapp's domain name, add static entries with `forward-to=` in the RouterOS built-in DNS proxy/cache.

   ```
   /ip/dns/static
     add name=app.example.com forward-to=155.18.71.103
     add regexp=".*\\example\\.com" forward-to=...
   ```

Comment: 6. I don't have access to Intranet router configuration, but i am sure it knows how to route to webapp. 
7. yes, i would prefer that.

Comment: 6. I don't have access to Intranet router configuration, but i am sure it knows how to route to webapp. 
7. yes, i would prefer that.

I was never configuring anything but home modem/router before, so yet i have to try your answer which i am thankful for.

Comment: #6 said "add routes _through_ the intranet gateway", not "_on_ the gateway". You add routes on your router through another router.